# "failed to execute mi command"

Tags: c, gdb, stm32

I am programming an STM32WB55 using STM32CubeIDE version 1.12.0.  My program tries to access the MCU's flash memory.  When I step through the program with the debugger, after the program sets the STRT bit in FLASH->CR, on the very next instruction the program crashes.  The debugger offers me decompilation with the message: "Break at address "0xfffffffe" with no debug information available, or outside of program code."  Yet my program nowhere accesses that address.  Here is the relevant code:

```
 /*
  * Check whether the FLASH->CR register was successfully unlocked.
  */
  if(0 == (0x80000000 & FLASH->CR))
  {
   /*
    * Check the BSY bit in FLASH->SR.
    */
    if(0 == (0x00010000 & FLASH->SR))
    {
     /*
      * Check the PESD bit in FLASH->SR.
      */
      if(0 == (0x00080000 & FLASH->SR))
      {
       /*
        * Clear the PGSERR bit if necessary.
        */
        if(0 != (0x00000080 & FLASH->SR))
        {
          FLASH->SR |= 0x00000080;
        }
       /*
        * Set erase-page to 0.
        */
        FLASH->CR &= ~0x000007f8;
       /*
        * Set the PER bit in FLASH->CR.
        */
        FLASH->CR |= 0x00000002;
       /*
        * Set the STRT bit in FLASH->CR.
        */
        FLASH->CR |= 0x00010000;  //<< Error occurs on the next instruction after this one. 
                                  //   It doesn't seem to matter what the next instruction is.
       /*
        * Clear the PER bit in FLASH->CR.
        */
        FLASH->CR &= ~0x00000002;
```

I also get a pop-up:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-next 1
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

I am using the latest version of STM32CubeIDE and the latest version of ST-Link.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Is it possible that you're trying to overwrite the part of the memory where the program is stored?

Comment: @user253751  No, the flash memory I am trying to erase begins at location 0x08000000 and runs for 512 kilobytes.  The program is not stored there.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to erase page 0, how do you know your program is not in page 0? (address 0x08000000-0x08000FFF)

Comment: @user253751 That must have been the source of the problem, since the problem went away when I tried erasing page 128 instead of page 0.  Thanks!